# Need to run Keycloak Docker Image with azure postgres sql

Tags: postgresql, azure, docker, keycloak

I need to run keycloak docker image present here (https://hub.docker.com/r/jboss/keycloak) with azure postgresql.

By default when i run with this command `docker run -p 8080:8080 jboss/keycloak` it takes by default db .

--It worked!!

Now I am trying to run it with azure postgressql according to documentation mentioned I try to pass azure db credentials like this in command like below:

```
docker run \
 -e DB_VENDOR=postgres \
 -e DB_ADDR=<AZUREDATASOURCE> \
 -e DB_USER=<DBUSER> \
 -e DB_PASSWORD=<DBPASS> \
 -e KEYCLOAK_USER=admin \
 -e KEYCLOAK_PASSWORD=admin \
 -p 8080:8080 \
 jboss/keycloak
```

But it is not working .

In the logs is showing `Connection refused`.

Comment: Did you add your client IP address in the Azure Postgres connectivity security firewall?

Answer (score 2):

> For keycloak 12.0.1 you still experience this problem when the
> database uses anything weaker than TLSv1.2. I think the problem
> occurs, because the RedHat UBI 8 image does not accept anything less
> than TLSv1.2.

as explained here [Keycloak 7.0.1 and MySQL (RDS) SSLHandshakeException: No appropriate protocol (protocol is disabled or cipher suites are inappropriate) for review](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58844503/keycloak-7-0-1-and-mysql-rds-sslhandshakeexception-no-appropriate-protocol-p)

I was having the same problem and then I realize that I was missing two environment variables `JDBC_PARAMS: "enabledTLSProtocols=TLSv1.2"` and `DB_DATABASE: <your_database_name>` also make sure that at the database end you have TLS enabled and it is set to version 1.2.

This is how your docker run would look like with all the parameters:

```
docker run \
-e DB_VENDOR=postgres \
-e DB_ADDR=xxxxxxxxxx.postgres.database.azure.com \
-e DB_USER=xxxxxxxxx@databaseservername \
-e DB_PASSWORD=<DBPASS> \
-e DB_PORT=5432 \
-e JDBC_PARAMS="enabledTLSProtocols=TLSv1.2" \
-e KEYCLOAK_USER=admin \
-e KEYCLOAK_PASSWORD=admin \
-p 8080:8080 \
jboss/keycloak
```

If this does not work make sure that your DB instance is accessible by using any tool such as [pgAdmin](https://www.pgadmin.org/) if not then check your DB server security settings and make sure that your IP address is allowed in the firewall settings so that your container can access the database.

Here is an example of a docker-compose file that works:

```
version: '3'
services:
        keycloak:
                image: jboss/keycloak

                environment:
                        DB_VENDOR: POSTGRES
                        DB_ADDR: xxxxxxxx.postgres.database.azure.com
                        DB_DATABASE: postgres
                        DB_USER: xxxxxx@xxxxxxxx
                        DB_SCHEMA: public
                        DB_PORT: 5432
                        DB_PASSWORD: xxxxxxxxxxxx
                        KEYCLOAK_USER: user
                        KEYCLOAK_PASSWORD: password
                        JDBC_PARAMS: "enabledTLSProtocols=TLSv1.2"
                        PROXY_ADDRESS_FORWARDING: "true"
                        
                ports:
                        - 8080:8080
```

Answer (score -1):

Try with passing DB credentials like below:

```
docker run \
 -e DB_VENDOR=POSTGRES\
 -e DB_ADDR=postgres \
 -e DB_DATABASE: keycloak \
 -e DB_USER=keycloak \
 -e DB_PASSWORD=password \
 -e KEYCLOAK_USER=admin \
 -e KEYCLOAK_PASSWORD=admin \
 -p 8080:8080 \
 jboss/keycloak
```

If still does not work better to go with [docker-compose file](https://github.com/jboss-dockerfiles/keycloak/blob/master/docker-compose-examples/keycloak-postgres.yml).